# Artifactory version searches fail to return more than 10 results

Tags: artifactory

I've seen this via the UI and directly through the REST API (which the UI of course uses) but the version search on a path does not return more than 10 results.

You can see this easily in the UI if you right click on a path with more than 10 versions and you choose Delete Versions.  You see an error stating:
"Search exceeded the limit and some versions are not shown. Try running this action from deeper node"

This seems like a bug.  I see no way to retrieve paginated results.  Also, I'm going to try uncommenting this line in the main properties file:

## artifactory.search.userQueryLimit=1000

But that seems ridiculous, what kind of default is 10?

Comment: The API endpoint I'm trying to use is api/search/versions.

Comment: Found a workaround - listing directory contents works fine, doesn't truncate at 10.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting seems to be related to the parameter that you added:
artifactory.search.userQueryLimit=1000
But one thing that you need to understand, the limit you got is that the search went over 1000 entries, not results. For that reason, the directory search worked. This search doesn't work with pagination. 
If you wish to use a more efficient way to search for your binaries you might want to consider using Artifactory AQL as you can see below: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language

---

Comment: Right, but I see that for artifact paths that contain far fewer than 1000 results.  Also, I did NOT set it, that is the default value.


I found a workaround, using the listDir endpoint.